# Assistance needed in iOS development with swift

Tags: ios

I have a graphic image drawn and swift code exported out of that drawing. I can use that exported core graphics code to draw that custom shaped switch control at runtime.

However I want to understand that how can I use that custom drawn switch control like a real component in app development as that custom drawn switch control is just a graphic.

I understand that I can draw a custom graphic for a button, I can use the .png as the image for button and use the base button control to respond to events. But how to use a custom switch control graphic as a component in real terms.

Anyone please help !!!

Regards,

Ujjwal

Comment: It's hard to understand what you mean. Maybe you could give an example. Are you talking about overriding `drawRect()`?

Comment: If you want to use your drawn view as a control e.g UIButton then just inherit your class from UIControl instead of UIView. You'll get all the touch events contained in a UIButton.